# Cannot read property "eventData" from undefined. while integrating third party solutions on Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

While following the [Google conferencing quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample) for integrating third party solutions on Google Calendar I get an error that prevents me to continue.

The code provided defines the `createConference` function as

```js
function createConference(arg) {
  const eventData = arg.eventData;
  const calendarId = eventData.calendarId;
  const eventId = eventData.eventId;
  // etc.
```

but running the script I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property "eventData" from undefined.`

Debugging the code I can see that the `arg` object whith which `createConference` is called is, in fact, undefined.

Why?

I checked also the [manifest specification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#conferencesolution) and it seems ok.

Comment: How are you calling the `createConference()` function? If you just run it from the script editor, all arguments will obviously be undefined. To run the script the right way, see [Run the script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample#run_the_script).

Comment: I'm stuck at the previous step, [Install a test deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample#install_a_test_deployment); the error is raised when executing `Open the CreateConf.gs file and click Run.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step to `Run` the script at [Install test deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/conferencing-sample#install_a_test_deployment) is only intended for you to authorize it, it will continue to fail and it is intended as @doubleunary mentioned in a comment.

The `arg` parameter is generated at calendar.google.com and it is an object that identifies the event as shown in the comments:

```
/*  @param {Object} arg The default argument passed to a 'onCreateFunction';
 *      it carries information about the Google Calendar event.
 *  @return {ConferenceData}
 */
```

The `onCreateFunction` is located at `appscript.json` as part of the "conferenceSolution" properties:

```
{
  "addOns": {
    "calendar": {
      "conferenceSolution": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "My Web Conference",
        "logoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/...",
        "onCreateFunction": "createConference"
      }],
      "currentEventAccess": "READ_WRITE"
    ...
}
```

After you finished that step you'll need to go to Google Calendar, open an event and you'll see that "My Web Conference" will be an video conferencing option:

[image]

Note that:

> The Failed to create conference error displays since the add-on isn't connected to a real third-party conferencing solution.

---

#### Reference:

[Calendar manifest resource -> ConferenceSolution](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#conferencesolution)